# Is there a Windows Store web service available for developers?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

Is there a Windows Store web service available for developers?

I need access to public information about the apps in the store.

Comment: You can access the sitemap for the Windows Store.  It's undocumented, but several developers have figured out how to use it... read the thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769726/metro-app-query-current-apps-in-windows-store#comment18955402_13769726) for more info.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need access to Windows Store data on registered apps using web services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580907/need-access-to-windows-store-data-on-registered-apps-using-web-services)

Comment: Really? I respectfully disagree with you guys closing my last post and this post. My postings have been valid questions. Thanks Sandra for posting a solution before they closed my question again. I now have a workaround that can help me access data.